# How to calculate date -N in linux shell scripting?

Tags: linux, date

I want to know how to calculate date-n where date is systems current date and N is number of days i want to add or subtract.

I am able to do get yesterday's date but dont know how to add or subtract no of days to get desired date :

```
date_dir=`date +%Y-%m-%d -d yesterday`
echo "$date_dir"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var=`date +%s`;

date=`date --date=@$var +%Y-%m-%d`

echo $date
```

you can add/subtract no of days you need. just remember it is in seconds

From man pages:

%s     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

Convert seconds since the epoch (1970-01-01 UTC) to a date

$ date --date='@2147483647'

edit: devNull provided better answer

Answer (score 4):

You can supply an argument `'-N days'` to the `-d` option:

```
$ date +%Y-%m-%d -d '-42 days'     # This would subtract 42 days from the current date
2013-10-30
$ date +%Y-%m-%d -d '+42 days'     # This would add 42 days to the current date
2014-01-22
```

and assign the result to a variable:

```
$ date_dir=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d '-42 days')
$ echo $date_dir 
2013-10-30
```

Comment: You could also do `date +%Y-%m-%d -d '42 days ago'. It's worth nothing that all these examples are with the GNU implementation of `date`. In BSD and UNIX this typically doesn't work, but sometimes the GNU version is also installed as `gdate`.

Comment: @janos Thanks for enlightening.  Since the question is tagged `linux`, it seemed safe to assume that `GNU date` was being used.

Comment: Totally, this is just a little extra. I've been very frustrated at some point in my life when I expected my trusty scripts I wrote in Linux to work in Solaris. Since then I know better, and try to be aware of the little differences.